# SQL Procedure causes DB locking when executed through Java

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

We have a legacy SQL Server procedure that works without any table locking issue in its current usage with a VB app (10+ yrs old).
Now, we are in migration project, but ONLY for the front-end so we are re-using the procedure as is by executing it on a JDBC connection.

The problem we are facing is, when the data being processed gets bigger, tables get locked out and no other user can access the system until the procedure finishes execution. Which has become a roadblock for our client-delivery.

I gave a try to MyBatis but did not help either.

**NOTE**: Procedure works perfectly fine - without any locking - when executed directly in MSSQL Server Management Studio

I'm not familiar with how locks are obtained and released when executing a stored procedure on a JDBC Connection.

Can anyone help me here? Any suggestions for resolving this issue?

Comment: From SQL it is only being executed one time, from the app if multiple users are using it, the same SP could be called multiple times at the same time causing the blocking/locking.  Depending on if you need to query with data locked on purpose (like making sure changes are made that are in processes before the query selects data or not) you can add NO LOCK to your queries.

Comment: Thanks Brad!
I forgot to mention that this is seen in dev env, even with just 2 users.

User 1: Login ->Navigate to the feature -> Trigger processing
User 2: Login is stuck/blocked

Comment: The connection manager through Java should not matter/be the cause.  Do you have your code you can show us?  You can look into NOLOCK and if that is ok to use it cold solve the issues

Comment: You can try the tools mentioned [here](https://www.brentozar.com/sql/locking-and-blocking-in-sql-server/). And blocking issues are very common with many discussions - a little searching will find these. But your first goal is to determine what is blocking and why.